# Create a "navigable" calendar in Joomla 2.5 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, joomla2.5

I need to modify a component, and I've create a simple calendar.

This calendar show some data from sql.

Now i want to make this calendar "navigable" using left and right arrow. What i want is to modify a variable in php, using javascript.

My calendar takes two arguments `$month`  and `$year`

With this I create a simple table

First of all I initialize some variables

```
<?php
            $dDay = 1;
            $currentDT = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$dDay,$year);
            $monthName = $modeldispo->getMonthName($month); 
            $daysInMonth = date("t",$currentDT);
            $stardDateOfWeek = date("w",$currentDT);
            $week = array("1"=>"Lun",
                          "2"=>"Mar",
                          "3"=>"Mer",
                          "4"=>"Gio",
                          "5"=>"Ven",
                          "6"=>"Sab",
                          "0"=>"Dom");?>
```

And than i begin to "draw" the table

```
<tr>
                
                <td class="tabletitle">Camera</td>
                 <?php
                 //draw the row for the days of the week
                  for($n=$stardDateOfWeek;$n<$daysInMonth+$stardDateOfWeek;$n++){
                         if($week[$n%7]=="Dom"){ ?>
                            <td class="tabletitleRed"><?php echo $week[$n%7]; ?></td>

                        <?php }
                         else {?>
                            <td class="tabletitle"><?php echo $week[$n%7]; ?></td>
                            
                    <?php
                         } }?>
</tr>
```

And then I do the same for the days of the month, printing the information carried from the db.

That's the result
[image: MyCalendar]

I just want to modify the global variable `$month` (and in case `$year` too) adding an event to the left and right arrow.

I tried to add a javascript function to my page, but it doesn't work. How can i add a javascript function to modify that php variable?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use just Javascript or a library like jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach an event handler to elements using jQuery.  First,  load the library by placing the following at the top of the layout files where the calendar is built out:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

Then at the bottom of the sane file add the following:

```
<script>
(function ($){
    $(document).on('click', '#myButtonId', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // insert code to alter variables here
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Not sure if you need help changing the variables in the DOM, but depending on how and where these values are stored the process differs.  If so,  let me know the discuss and I can post an example.

Comment: JHtmlJquery is not a class in Joomla! 2.5, maybe it was introduced in 3.0 with the other UI changes. How can I use it in Joomla! 2.5?

Comment: So i googled and installed a plugin...now it works! thanks a lot!